# Problem with ConjugateTranspose on 1D array

Tags: numerics, bugs, complex, numerical-value, numeric-array

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier, fixed in 13.0.**

---

Suppose I have a normalized numerical 1D array, `B1`,

```
    B1 = {0.9269939990888411` - 0.22888585272824927` I, 
   1.3877787807814457`*^-17 + 0.` I, -2.7755575615628914`*^-17 - 
    1.8041124150158794`*^-16 I, 
   0.05746221176648221` + 
    0.10518387310098759` I, -1.3877787807814457`*^-17 - 
    9.020562075079397`*^-17 I, 
   0.0574622117664822` + 0.10518387310098762` I, 
   0.0574622117664822` + 0.10518387310098765` I, 
   2.0816681711721685`*^-17 - 3.469446951953614`*^-17 I, 
   0.` - 1.3877787807814457`*^-16 I, 
   0.057462211766482196` + 0.10518387310098765` I, 
   0.05746221176648217` + 0.10518387310098765` I, 
   2.7755575615628914`*^-17 - 6.938893903907228`*^-17 I, 
   0.05746221176648225` + 0.1051838731009876` I, 
   3.469446951953614`*^-17 - 3.469446951953614`*^-17 I, 
   5.0306980803327406`*^-17 - 
    3.469446951953614`*^-17 I, -0.04191842262180526` + 
    0.01851810652627404` I};
```

Then `$Version == "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"` gives the very sensible

```
Conjugate[B1] . B1
Transpose[Conjugate[B1]] . B1
```

as both `1. + 0. I`.  However

```
ConjugateTranspose[B1] . B1
```

gives `0.761773 - 0.353375 I`, which is the same as what I get for `B1.B1`.

*Questions*:

- What gives?
- Is this known / expected behavior?
- Is this a bug?

Comment: ConjugateTranspose needs a matrix as input. If you give it a vector, it leaves it alone. Try: `ConjugateTranspose[{1,I}]`  If this is a bug or a misuse of the command, I do not know.

Comment: Questions that might help diagnose or confirm this: Is `Conjugate[Transpose[B1]]==ConjugateTranspose[B1]` as the docs claim? Is `B1==Transpose[B1]]` ? Is `Conjugate[B1]==Transpose[Conjugate[B1]]` And do some or all of those work as expected if `B1` is a well behaved matrix instead of a vector?

Comment: @DanielHuber the docs say "ConjugateTranspose[m] is equivalent to Conjugate[Transpose[m]]. »" which clearly isn't true in the above case.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you report this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: @Bill, `ConjugateTranspose[B1] == Conjugate[Transpose[B1]]` gives `False`.  `B1==Transpose[B1]` gives `True`.  `Conjugate[B1]==Transpose[Conjugate[B1]]` gives `True`.  To test the matrix case, you can try `ConjugateTranspose[{B1, B1}] == Conjugate[Transpose[{B1, B1}]]` which gives `True`.

Comment: I emailed wolfram, will report when I hear back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is resolved in version 13.0 (`$Version == "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`).